# How do I add multiple spaces with ES6 string templates?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a string template that currently looks like this:

```
var option = "\u00A0" + "\u00A0" + "\u00A0" + "\u00A0" + option.name;
```

that I am trying to change to the new ES6 syntax

```
var option = `    ${option.name}`
```

But when it shows up in on screen none of the spaces are in the ES6 version or there is no 4 space indention on the strings in which I am specifying it.  The problem might have something to do with me using these strings in as `options` in a `select`.  Any ideas?

Comment: You can still use the unicode syntax. You don’t need to separate them into individual strings. `"\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0" + option.name` or the ES6-equivalent. Or you use the shorter `\xa0`.

Comment: *"But when it shows up in on screen none of the spaces are in the ES6 version"* I think you have to provide more information. [The string clearly has spaces in the ES6 version](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=true&evaluate=false&loose=false&spec=false&code=var%20option%20%3D%20%60%20%20%20%20%24%7Boption.name%7D%60&playground=true). I guess you mean that the spaces don't show in the HTML which is not surprising. Space (`\u0020`) and `\u00A0` are two different characters. What prevents you from using `\u00A0` in the template literal?

Comment: @FelixKling - You are absolutely right.  It must have something to do with the `option` and not the string interpolation.

Comment: It has something to do with that you use a different white space character in the second example. The equivalent would be `\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0${option.name}`. What make you think you could switch `\u00A0` with a different character?

Comment: @FelixKling -  Please make that the answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

In the first example you are using a non-breaking space (`\u00A0`) and in the second example a normal space (`\u0020`). So in addition to changing the syntax, you also changed the characters.

This doesn't really have anything to do with ES6 in particular. If you use the same character it will work as expected:

```
var option = `\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0${option.name}`;
```